# Building a wish list

Tags: php

I have the task of building a wish list, where simply a user can add a products to a list.

There are no user accounts on the site, so I am trying to find a way to do this without the user having to login.

The wish list does not need to be remembered for weeks, just a few days.

What method would be best to use?

IP address?
Sessions / Cookies?

Any advice would be great.

Thank you

Comment: You can find information for this all over the internet. Stack Overflow is for questions about **specific** code when implementing your idea.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random string. Use this as the key in your database table, and send it to the user as a cookie. You could also give them a URL that contains the key as a parameter, so they can bookmark it, and not lose their wishlist if they clear their cookies.

Comment: Setting cookies for this kind of a purpose is certainly bad practise in any modern web app.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 LocalStorage
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

You can store entries in the user's browser itself and your app can retrieve it once the user comes back onto your app again. Best to do your app with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would say cookies is probably best or maybe doing it with IP and cookies.

Cookies, just in-case they change IP often (which does happen) or both could be better.

Comment: Tracking by IP is poor, since users behind a firewall often have the same IP.

Comment: I do agree, which is why I said cookies would be best.